# What the EA stands for in Java Version ?

Tags: build, version, java

`> java -version`

```
java version "1.7.0_10-ea"                                   <----      !
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_10-ea-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.6-b04, mixed mode)
```

Am I running the last `JDK 7u10` please ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

EA stands for "Early Access", EA is a preview release for the upcoming version of the software.

Checkout this **[link](http://java.com/en/download/faq/oem.xml)**:-

> **EA release**
>
> EA stands for "Early Access", EA is a preview release for the upcoming
> version of the software. This release may contain many new features
> and bug fixes and as a preview may contain some unexpected issues. It
> is not recommended that this preview release be used in a production
> environment. Please upgrade to the latest release on java.com

**On a side note:-**

There are two more releases:-

> **OEM release**
>
> OEM stands for "original equipment manufacturer".  An early version of
> Java 1.6.0-oem was provided to OEMs. The OEM term will not be used in
> subsequent releases of 1.6. Please upgrade to the latest release on
> java.com
>
> **Beta release**
>
> A beta release is a 'stable' preview release which is tested for bugs.
> Beta releases are often made available to the general public to
> download and test. Please upgrade to the latest release on java.com

Answer (score 10):

`-ea` stands for "early access":

> http://java.com/en/download/faq/oem.xml
>
> EA stands for "Early Access", EA is a preview release for the upcoming version of the software. This release may contain many new features and bug fixes and as a preview may contain some unexpected issues. It is not recommended that this preview release be used in a production environment. Please upgrade to the latest release on java.com